# CPU context switch per/second increasing with network traffic increasing

Tags: ubuntu, central-processing-unit, context-switch

I have server with ubuntu server operation system, i have some applications on it which works with network. With an increase in network traffic, CPU context swithching and interrupts are also increases 40 - 60 k per/second. What i must fix kernel optimizaion, NIC optimization maybe or what?

**UPDATE**

First of all thank you for you answers. I have 8 CPU. My cat /proc/interrupts

```
          CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
  0:    6938741    6966303    6934714    6881839    6895772    6883046    6952545    6909960   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          0          0          1          0          0          1          1          1   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          0          1          0          0          1          1          2          1   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb2
 17:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3
 18:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4
 19:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb5
 21:         21         23         22         21         23         21         23         21   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ipmi_si
 22:          3          5          6          6          2          5          3          6   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb6, hpilo
 23:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   radeon
 41:     275729        555        587        549     275294        563        583        600   PCI-MSI-edge      cciss0
 42:          2          0          2          1          1          1          2          1   PCI-MSI-edge      cciss1
 46:   31600723   31636789   31668261   31721092   31643480   31719981   31650284   31692948   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
NMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:   42250721   42318004   19164905   20751945   32012455   25335850   15889990   15935085   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RES:  104005816   96594384   40149041   34906154   77175689   55787936   28455228   25633969   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:     204860     543304    1318717    1176681     431344     876239    1046465    1257472   Function call interrupts
TLB:     308034     229917     230598     299353     362103     478994     256456     212019   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:       1263       1263       1263       1263       1263       1263       1263       1263   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
```

I have very big:

```
 RES:  104150407   96747853   40291367   35052019   77327041   55940217   28595113   25775538   Rescheduling
```

from which it depends?

My network cards: bnx2: Broadcom NetXtreme II Gigabit Ethernet Driver bnx2 v2.1.6 (Mar 7, 2011)

**UPDATE 2**

I made: ethtool -k eth0

And see: large-receive-offload: off

How can i make on it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is that traffic? Have you many small packets coming in/going out? Big ones? Can you raise the MTU value without problems?

Comment: it's tcp traffic (xmpp) many in/out packets.

Answer (score 3):

I assume these are legitimate interrupts because of network load, and not a result of hardware/driver problem. So:

You can invest into [TCP-offload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine) network card (TOE), if you deal with TCP traffic. It does some processing of TCP/IP in the network card chip, and raises less interrupts (and context switches). Check if your kernel/OS/application/traffic supports it.

Alternatively, take a look into [Large receive offload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_receive_offload) (LRO), which is a light-weight approach.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware interrupts are a normal part of computer operation.  Your NIC is going "hey! hey! hey! hey!" telling your CPU that it needs attention.

*Excessive* hardware interrupts are typically caused by bad drivers. So the first thing I would look at are your NIC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

That indeed is a huge number of interrupts. This often is an APIC Problem, though.

> cat /proc/interrupts

should tell. If you only see your interrupts hitting CPU0 try

> echo "2" > /proc/irq/"somenumber"/smp_affinity

Which should push the irqs of process "somenumber" on CPU2.